# Delay in loading Startup application WinCE 6.0

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded, platform-builder, windows-embedded-standard

We have added MFC application in \Windows\startup folder to run application after WinCE 6.0 boot successfully.
Below are the software we have installed for Generating WinCE 6.0 OS image.
1) Visual Studio 2005
2) Windows CE 6.0 toolkit 
3) Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 & Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Platform Builder Service Pack 1
4) Installed device specific BSP.

We have selected Hive based registry while creating OS design. Everything working fine, the application is loading with no delay after OS boots up successfully.

Problem:
Our project requirement is to incorporate the WinCE 6.0 release updates and Cumulative Product Update Rollup Package. So we have download and installed Windows CE 6.0 R2 update from below location:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18111

After installing WinCE 6.0 R2 update, we are facing strange issue. After OS boots up, the loading of the application is taking 10-12 seconds very first time. We are facing delay in starting up application very first time, after that application startup normally(On subsequent power on device) without any delay. 
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue. Is there is any bug in WinCE 6.0 R2 update, as we are facing this issue after installing R2 updates.

Thanks